# Python GTK module not found with Enthought's Canopy

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, canopy

In the simple code

> import gtk
>
> class GettingStarted:
>
> ```
> def __init__(self):
>     window = gtk.Window()
>     window.show()
> ```
>
> GettingStarted()
> gtk.main()

I receive an import error at the lines

> from glib._glib import *
>
> _PyGLib_API = _glib._PyGLib_API
>
> DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

For background, I am running 64bit windows7 and using 64bit canopy and I got my modules here:
[http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

I downloaded the following 64bit files into the site-packages folder accompanied by Canopy

> C:...\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Lib\site-packages\

pygtk-2.22.0,

pygobject-2.28.6,

pycairo-1.10.0,

python-dateutil-1.5,

pyparsing-2.0.1,

numpy-1.7.1,

matplotlib-1.3.1rc2

Comment: I've never succeeded at getting 64-bit pygtk working on windows. Do you have a need for 64-bit? Using 32-bit Canopy and the 32-bit PyGTK all-in-one installer is much more straightforwrd.

Answer (score 0):

The last 4 packages that you list are already in Canopy. I do not recommend replacing them.

The first 3 packages that you list should be installed by running them (the download files are executables) not by copying them into site-packages. Before you execute them, be sure that you have made Canopy be your default Python or they will install into whatever Python is your default.

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled as you suggested, but the error persists. Does gtk require gtk+ http://www.gtk.org/download/win64.php ? If so, I don't see any executables for that download.